# Как вывести всю строку в FOR..IN не перечисляя столбцы?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Как вывести всю строку в FOR..IN в DBMS_OUTPUT?

```
begin
   FOR colind IN (select 1 as t from dual)
   LOOP

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(colind.t); --тут столбец надо указывать, а мне нужно сразу всю строку

   END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Это невозможно, столбцы надо указывать.

Comment: Dbms_sql использовать нужно будет вам